# Vertical centering inside an overprint

Tags: beamer

Is there an "easy" way to vertically center stuff in an `overprint` environment?

Based on the current answer, this is my test document

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{listings}
\long\def\opcenter#1{\vfill\smash{\begin{minipage}[c]{\linewidth}#1\end{minipage}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]
  \begin{overprint}
    \onslide<1>
      \opcenter{A short paragraph}
    \onslide<2>
      \opcenter{A\\
        longer\\
        paragraph\\
        with\\
        a\\
        few\\
        lines}
    \onslide<3>
      \opcenter{
        \begin{block}{Title}
          A block \\
          with\\
          a\\
          few lines
        \end{block}
      }
    \onslide<4>
      \opcenter{
        One paragraph

        Plus something else
      }
     \onslide<5>
       \opcenter{
         \begin{lstlisting}
And verbatim stuff
         \end{lstlisting}
       }
  \end{overprint}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

And the problem now is with paragraph breaks (a replacement for `\smash`?) and verbatim content (`listings`).

Answer (score 3):

The idea is to use `\smash` to hide the height of the text, use `\vfill`s to center vertically and then use [`minibox`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/minibox) to get line breaking in the text.

You could also use `minipage` in place of `minibox`, but the former requires 
specifying the width.

---

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{minibox}
\begin{document}
\long\def\opcenter#1{\vfill\smash{\minibox{#1}}}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{overprint}
    \onslide<1>
    \opcenter{A short paragraph}
    \onslide<2>
    \opcenter{A\\
        longer\\
        paragraph\\
        with\\
        a\\
        few\\
        lines}

% This frame uses minipage instead of minibox. minibox
% does not accept a block as its argument.
\onslide<3>
      \vfill\smash{\begin{minipage}[c]{1.0\linewidth}
        \begin{block}{Title}
          A block \\
          with\\
          a\\
          few lines
        \end{block}
      \end{minipage}}\vfill
  \end{overprint}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: That's fine, except it doesn't accept a `block` as argument. I'm updating the question.

Comment: @Jellby See my updated answer for the third frame. You can use `minipage` as well if you do not mind specifying the width. Now you can update the macro to your taste.

Comment: I'm sorry, I think I have to add new "requirements" :D See the updated question, I need it to work with paragraphs, and `listings` support would be welcome.