# Beamer overprint: center content vertically

Tags: beamer, vertical-alignment, alignment

In this MWE, I want the images to be centered vertically:

```tex
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{mwe}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \hrulefill{}
  \begin{columns}
    \begin{column}{0.4\textwidth}
      Some text.
    \end{column}
    \begin{column}{0.55 \textwidth}
      \begin{overprint}
        \onslide<1>\centering
        \includegraphics[width=.25\linewidth]{image-a.pdf}
        \onslide<2>\centering
        \includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{image-b.pdf}
      \end{overprint}
    \end{column}
  \end{columns}
  \hrulefill{}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

I know about [question 165537](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/165537/vertical-centering-inside-an-overprint), but the proposed solution there seems make problems due to the `\smash` command.

[image: The output]

Answer (score 2):

Quick & dirty with `\raisebox` (maybe there are better methods I don't know).

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{mwe}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \hrulefill{}
  \begin{columns}
    \begin{column}{0.4\textwidth}
      Some text.
    \end{column}
    \begin{column}{0.55 \textwidth}
      \begin{overprint}
        \onslide<1>\centering
        \raisebox{-.25\textheight}{\raisebox{-.45\height}{\includegraphics[width=.25\linewidth]{image-a.pdf}}}
        \onslide<2>\centering
        \raisebox{-.25\textheight}{\raisebox{-.45\height}{\includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{image-b.pdf}}}
      \end{overprint}
    \end{column}
  \end{columns}
  \hrulefill{}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]